Error attempting to use dynamic columns in SQL Server stored procedure
I saw several posts on Stack Overflow describing how to use dynamic columns in a SQL Server stored procedure, but my attempts result in an error message regarding the dynamic column name I am trying to use.

Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_FetchBrandImagesNoCatID, Line 21 [Batch Start Line 2]
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'share_on_macy' to data type int.

The stored procedure works fine when I don't attempt to reference the dynamic column name, it's only when I added the use of dynamic column name that the error appears (I am using SQL Server 2014).
Here is the stored procedure: the error occurs with the attempt to use either @APPEARONLANGUAGE or @SHAREONCOLUMNNAME which are the column names passed to the stored procedure. Both columns are defined in the table as INT:
USE [test]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_FetchBrandImagesNoCatID] 
    @BRANDID varchar(10),
    @STORE varchar(30),
    @APPEARONLANGUAGE varchar(100),
    @SHAREONCOLUMNNAME varchar(100),
    @RECS int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT TOP (@RECS) * 
    FROM  
        (SELECT 
             *, 
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY adminsort1 DESC, adminsort2 DESC, randomsort ASC) AS rownum 
         FROM  
             (SELECT DISTINCT TOP 100 PERCENT  
                  retail_images.id, retail_images.guid,
                  retail_images.folder, retail_images.filename, 
                  CAST(retail_images.captionenglish AS nvarchar(500)) AS caption, 
                  CAST(retail_images.source AS nvarchar(500)) AS source,  
                  b.folder AS bfolder, b.filename AS bfilename,
                  retail_customers.displayname,  
                  (SELECT Count(*) 
                   FROM retail_image_likes 
                   WHERE retail_images.id = retail_image_likes.imageid) AS LikeCount,
                  retail_customers.id AS profileid,
                  retail_images.videoid, retail_images.videopadding,
                  retail_images.duration, retail_images.filename_cloud,
                  retail_images.bucket_cloud, retail_images.store,
                  retail_images.cloudflareid, b.cloudflareid AS bcloudflareid, 
                  retail_images.cloudflareid_chinese, 
                  retail_images.cloudflareid_taiwan,
                  retail_images.cloudflareid_spanish,  
                  SUBSTRING(CAST(retail_images.guid AS varchar(50)), 28, 1) AS randomsort,
                  retail_images.admin_set_priority AS adminsort1,  
                  retail_images.prioritypoints AS adminsort2  
              FROM 
                  retail_images  
              LEFT OUTER JOIN 
                  retail_images b ON (retail_images.customerid = b.customerid 
                                      AND retail_images.customerid <> 0  
                                      AND b.filetype = N'M' 
                                      AND b.approved = 1)  
              LEFT OUTER JOIN 
                  retail_customers ON (retail_images.customerid = retail_customers.id)  
              LEFT OUTER JOIN  
                  Products ON (Products.productid = retail_images.productid1 
                               OR Products.productid = retail_images.productid2 
                               OR Products.productid = retail_images.productid3 
                               OR Products.productid = retail_images.productid4 
                               OR Products.productid = retail_images.productid5 
                               OR Products.productid = retail_images.productid6 
                               OR Products.productid = retail_images.productid7 
                               OR Products.productid = retail_images.productid8)   
                            AND Products.brandid = @BRANDID 
              INNER JOIN 
                  Brand ON (retail_images.brandid = Brand.id 
                            OR Products.brandid = Brand.id)
                        AND Brand.id = @BRANDID 
              WHERE  
                  (retail_images.approved = 1 
                   AND retail_images.hidden = 0) 
                  AND (@APPEARONLANGUAGE = 1)   
                  AND ((retail_images.store = '@STORE') OR (@SHAREONCOLUMNNAME = 1))  
                  AND (retail_images.filetype = N'I')  
                  AND (retail_images.is_posting <> 1)  
                  AND retail_images.loginrequired = 0  
                  AND retail_images.is_subscription = 0  
              ORDER BY 
                  adminsort1 DESC, adminsort2 DESC, randomsort ASC) subqry) subqry2  
    ORDER BY  
        rownum
END

When I invoke the stored procedure from SQL Server Management Studio "Execute Stored Procedure", I provide the 5 parameters in the dialog box provided then upon pressing OK, then I get the error.
I must be missing something obvious, and I apologize in advance if so, but this is my first attempt at using dynamic column names in a stored procedure and I'm grateful for any help!

Some basic formatting of that mess would be a good start to reeading comprehension. I see no indication that dynamic SQL is actually being used: that would need to create an SQL statement dynamically in an nvarchar(max) and run sp_executesql. You can't just plonk a column name in a variable and pretend it will inject it in a normal query, that's not how SQL works. Also column and object names should be stored in sysname variables, not varchar(100), and need to be safely escaped using the QUOTENAME function.

So many other issues as well: Use of '@STORE' in quotes is incorrect. Lack of short table aliases is also not helping comprehension. Use of TOP 100 PERCENT is completely meaningless.  Use of DISTINCT seems to indicate poorly thought out joins leading to duplicate rows. Sorting by a rownumber is the same effect but less efficient as sorting by the very same ORDER BY clause of that rownumber. Multiple columns such as productid1 productid2 etc indicate improper database normalization. I'm going to hazard a guess the indexing and query plan are awful as well.

Also note: you should not use the sp_ prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has reserved that prefix for its own use (see Naming Stored Procedures), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. It's also bad for your stored procedure performance. It's best to just simply avoid sp_ and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Thanks for the helpful suggestions - I've learned a lot already :)
The solution was to declare a variable string to contain the entire query which allowed for the flexible use of the passed parameters:
USE [test_inventory]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_FetchBrandImagesNoCatID] 
    @BRANDID varchar(10),
    @STORE varchar(30),
    @APPEARONLANGUAGE varchar(100),
    @SHAREONCOLUMNNAME varchar(100),
    @RECS varchar(6)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @SQL AS nvarchar(max)

SET NOCOUNT ON;

SET @SQL = N'
SELECT TOP ' + (@RECS) + N' * FROM  
(SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY adminsort1 desc,adminsort2 desc,randomsort asc) as rownum 
FROM  (SELECT DISTINCT TOP 100 PERCENT retail_images.id,retail_images.guid,retail_images.folder,retail_images.filename, 
CAST(retail_images.captionenglish as nvarchar(500)) as caption, CAST(retail_images.source as nvarchar(500)) as source,  
b.folder as bfolder,b.filename as bfilename,retail_customers.displayname,  (SELECT Count(*) 

FROM retail_image_likes
 
WHERE retail_images.id = retail_image_likes.imageid) AS LikeCount ,retail_customers.id as profileid,
retail_images.videoid,retail_images.videopadding,retail_images.duration,retail_images.filename_cloud,
retail_images.bucket_cloud,retail_images.store,retail_images.cloudflareid,b.cloudflareid as bcloudflareid, 
retail_images.cloudflareid_chinese,retail_images.cloudflareid_taiwan,retail_images.cloudflareid_spanish,  
SUBSTRING(CAST(retail_images.guid as varchar(50)),28,1) as randomsort ,retail_images.admin_set_priority as adminsort1,  
retail_images.prioritypoints as adminsort2  

FROM retail_images  

LEFT OUTER JOIN retail_images b  ON ( retail_images.customerid = b.customerid AND retail_images.customerid<>0  AND  
b.filetype=N''M'' AND b.approved=1)
  
LEFT OUTER JOIN retail_customers ON (retail_images.customerid = retail_customers.id )
  
LEFT OUTER JOIN  Products ON   (Products.productid = retail_images.productid1 OR  
Products.productid = retail_images.productid2 OR  Products.productid = retail_images.productid3 OR  
Products.productid = retail_images.productid4 OR  Products.productid = retail_images.productid5 OR  
Products.productid = retail_images.productid6 OR  Products.productid = retail_images.productid7 OR  
Products.productid = retail_images.productid8)   AND Products.brandid = ' + @BRANDID + N'

INNER JOIN Brand ON (retail_images.brandid = Brand.id OR Products.brandid = Brand.id)AND Brand.id = ' + 
@BRANDID + N'

WHERE  (retail_images.approved=1 AND retail_images.hidden=0) 
AND (retail_images.appearon' + @APPEARONLANGUAGE + N'=1)   
AND ((retail_images.store = ''' + @STORE + N''') OR (retail_images.share_on_' + @SHAREONCOLUMNNAME + N'=1))  
AND (retail_images.filetype=N''I'')  AND 
( retail_images.is_posting <> 1 )  AND retail_images.loginrequired = 0  AND retail_images.is_subscription = 0  

ORDER BY adminsort1 desc,adminsort2 desc,randomsort asc ) subqry) subqry2  
ORDER BY rownum'

EXEC(@SQL)

END



This code is dangerous, it should not be used. It is wide open to SQL Injection attacks.

You've also ignore all the advice in the comments; the formatting is gone, making it an unreadable mess, the data types are wrong, it still uses the sp_ prefix, the DISTINCT and TOP are still there... It's still has all the problems your code had before and is actually worse as it's now a massive security issue as well...

To demonstrate how dangerous this is, after trial and error from the errors I got from the data engine when injecting stuff, I worked out how to use your query to create a new sysadmin on the instance: db<>fiddle. Of course, you may have restricted permissions (so you'd get the same error that I do in the fiddle), but a malicious individual will likely be able to at least breach your data with the above. Example against the sys objects: db<>fiddle
